# go-rod triggering anti-virus

Tags: go, go-modules

I'm using a sample script taken directly from go-rods website
https://go-rod.github.io/#/

But for some reason, it's triggering my anti-virus. I've never had this problem with any golang packages

Here is the code that I am using

```
import (
    "time"

    "github.com/go-rod/rod"
)

func main() {
    browser := rod.New().MustConnect().NoDefaultDevice()
    page := browser.MustPage("https://www.wikipedia.org/").MustWindowFullscreen()

    page.MustElement("#searchInput").MustInput("earth")
    page.MustElement("#search-form > fieldset > button").MustClick()

    page.MustWaitLoad().MustScreenshot("a.png")
    time.Sleep(time.Hour)
}
```

I would think this would be a false positive, but why would any malware code be linked to something like go-rod?

I would think this would be a false positive, but why would any malware code be linked to something like go-rod?

(I am using Windows Defender)

Comment: The binary does something that looks suspicious according to your anti-virus program. If this is a false positive, then file an issue with your antivirus.

Comment: It's Windows Defender

Answer (score 1):

go-rod uses a binary of [leakless](https://github.com/ysmood/leakless), which is used to cleanly close subprocesses (such as the browser in the case of rod). It is being detected by your antivirus, because leakless is also used by popular malware.

Solution 1: Disable leakless by creating your own *Launcher and set its [leakless property](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-rod/rod@v0.79.0/lib/launcher#Launcher.Leakless) to false.

Solution 2: Tell your antivirus to ignore the leakless binary.

Comment: Solution 3: Sign the `leakless` binary with your own code signing certificate. This is the best option if you plan to distribute your program to end customers.